# Optimize mysql table to avoid locking

Tags: mysql

How do I optimize mysql tables to not use locking? Can I alter table to 'turn off' locking all the time.

Situation:
I have app which use database of 15M records. Once weekly scripts doing some task (insert/update/delete) for 20 hours, and app servers that feed data to front end (web server), and that is fine, very small performance loss I see during that time.

Problem:
Once monthly I need to optimize table, since huge number of records is out there it take 1-2 hours to finish this task (starting optimize from mysql command line, or phpMyAdmin, same) and in that period mysql DOESN'T SERVE data to front end (I suppose it is about locking tables for optimize)

Question:
So how to optmize tables to avoid locking, since there is only reading of data (no insert or update) so I suppose 'unlocking' while optimize, in this case can't make any damage?

Comment: is it table Innodb/MySAM? that will have a major impact

Answer (score 2):

In case your table engine is InnoDB and MySQL version is > 5.6.17 - the lock won't happen. Actually there will be lock, but for VERY short period.

> Prior to Mysql 5.6.17, OPTIMIZE TABLE does not use online DDL.
>   Consequently, concurrent DML (INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE) is not permitted
>   on a table while OPTIMIZE TABLE is running, and secondary indexes are
>   not created as efficiently.
>
> As of MySQL 5.6.17, OPTIMIZE TABLE uses online DDL for regular and
>   partitioned InnoDB tables. The table rebuild, triggered by OPTIMIZE
>   TABLE and performed under the cover by ALTER TABLE ... FORCE, is
>   performed in place and only locks the table for a brief interval,
>   which reduces downtime for concurrent DML operations.

[Optimize Tables Official Ref.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/optimize-table.html)
Just better prepare free space that is > than the space currently occupied by your table, because whole table copy can happen for index rebuild.